# Clustering standard errors in panel data

Tags: panel-data, standard-error

I have a panel data with companies and years as panel indicators. My test variable of interest is the level of corruption in the country in which the firm is located, which is a continuous variable that varies over time. My dependent variable is a firm level financial misconduct score. So my depednent variable is measured at the firm level, whereas my independent variable of intrest is measured at the country level. My control variables are measured either at firm or country level.
In my regression model I include country, year, and industry fixed effects (industry is the industry in which a firm operates).

My question is that, theoretically, should I cluster standard errors by firm, by country, or by both? In practice, I find that the statistical significance of the coefficient of my test variable is sensative to the clustering of standard errors.

I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Welcome. Is your primary independent variable of interest at the *country* level? Also, do you suspect firms *within a particular industry* are more or less insulated from financial misconduct?